# php upload file from server to another via FTP?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, curl, ftp

Hi I have a problem in transferring file from server to server I want to copy
file like:

http://mysite1.com/myfile.jpg  <-- I want this to copy or upload via ftp to mysite2.com

For example: http://mysite1.com/myfile.jpg upload to http://mysite2.com/fileuploads/

How to do this via PHP FTP transferring? Any hardcoder here can help my problem?

Comment: What's your problem? Have you read through this: http://no.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php ?

Comment: You say you have a problem in transferring a file from one server to another. You never state what is your problem. You just say give me teh codez. You don't have to be a hardcoder to read the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here's one sample code, but you should read and try on your own before asking:

```
$connection = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, $mode);

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);
```

Hope it helps you getting started