# Upload single file to multiple servers

Tags: php

there is a lot about how to upload multiple files to a server, but what I need here is how to upload a file to multiple servers synchronously (like file miroring websites) in php.
thank you

**update**

ok my question is how filemiroring websites work?

Comment: You can use php to upload files from one server to others. You cannot use php to upload files from a client browser to serveral server. Your question is not precise enough what you want to achieve. Upload from client to server or from server to server. You only tagged the question with php which is an indicator for the later as php has nothing to do with the file upload from a browser (except that it has to accept and store it later).

Comment: i want to upload the file from one server to multiple servers (like file miroring websites)

Comment: I think: once he submitted the form (file upload) he want the file to be uploaded to original server plus additional servers... this can be done by both PHP and AJAX, for PHP, you can send the file to other servers from original server using FTP or any other protocol, and by using AJAX I think you can start uploading to multiple server theoretically, But I never tested that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the file to another server using FTP: [php upload file from server to another via FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306975/php-upload-file-from-server-to-another-vie-ftp)

You may also upload the file to other  server using CURL:
[Remote Server File Upload Via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232605/remote-server-file-upload-via-php)

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

A browser sends a file using a POST request to *one* server. The HTML spec does not include uploading to multiple servers.

Therefore, you have to roll your own application for copying the file. Another option would be to use 3rd party product.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you know any 3rd party

Comment: Could be bitorrentSync. Or you could create a rsync script that sync your files between the servers

Answer (score 0):

you can upload images to multiple servers at same time with the use PHP CURL.it will enables the gross domain support to your working domain.