# transfer file from path to path in ftp using php

Tags: php, ftp

Here is my prob in Brief.

I know how to upload a file to server using FTP with programming language PHP.
But is that possible to transfer files from one directory to another directory. In the same server.... 
I have the two paths of the directorys...
Any idea how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php upload file from server to another via FTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306975/php-upload-file-from-server-to-another-via-ftp)

Comment: work on the same server?